# custom django management command not working when deployed as egg

Tags: django, deployment, path, egg

I've made a little django **app**, only one management command, which is packaged into an egg.

If I unzip the egg into a blank django **project**, add it to installed_apps, the management command works.

However, when it is `easy_install`ed onto a server and although it's in the path (I can import the `Command` class  on the command line), and in `INSTALLED_APPS`, the management command isn't registered. It's installed from the egg into the site-packages.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Django specifically looks up subdirectories. See `find_commands` function in [`core/management/init.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/__init__.py#L22). So it won't work with eggs obviously. The easy fix would be to not distribute your app as an egg. There are [only few good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170477/why-would-one-use-an-egg-over-an-sdist) to do it nowadays anyway.

You can tell the installer to unpack eggs in the setup.py file. Read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604694/102852) for details. In that case management commands should work.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I should have mentioned that the eggs are installed with easy_install. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Oatman, have you tried adding `zip_safe=False` to setup.py? http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#setting-the-zip-safe-flag

Answer (score 0):

Even if you package it as an eg, you still need it in your `installed_apps` for django to pick it up.