# How does django register management commands

Tags: django, command, system

I'm having a weird issue with something in a deployed django app (long [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317950/custom-django-management-command-not-working-when-deployed-as-egg)).
Something that might help me is to know:

**How django goes about detecting and maintaining a list of active management commands?**

Answer (score 4):

Some things you should consider if you have troubles executing a management command:

1. The app containing the command has to be in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. To be recognized as an app the package has to contain a `models.py` (although it can be empty).
3. All packages need to have an `__init__.py` file (your app's directory as well as the `management` and `command` folder).
4. Sometimes Django seems to be choking on something like an `ImportError` that doesn't get displayed properly - so it might help to open a `manage.py shell` and try something like `import MyCommand from myapp.management.commands.mycommand`.

Comment: Ooh, thanks; I'd missed the `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` bit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks for any module under `management.commands` inside installed applications. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/ for more details.

The code looks for Python modules in `management/commands` direction in each installed app using [pkgutil.iter_modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules).

Comment: I know.. but HOW does he do that? What python methods does it use to find 'Command' classes?