# Issue trying to pass file as an argument to a custom management command

Tags: python, linux, django

Here is my code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import sys, os, shutil

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--file', nargs='1', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        lists_file = options['file']
```

However, when I try to run the command with:

```
./manage.py: error: no such option: --file=test_lists.txt
```

I get an error:

```
Usage: ./manage.py create_test_lists [options] 

./manage.py: error: no such option: --file
```

I have verified that test_lists.txt exists in the same directory as manage.py.  In addition the file for my command is located at *my_app/management/commands/create_test_lists.py* which seems right.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you done all these steps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14320690/196206

Answer (score 4):

- No need for `nargs` if it's just one
- Use `argparse.FileType` instread of `str`
- See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects

Example:

```
import argparse

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        lists_file = options['file']
```

Comment: Having just implemented this answer, using Django 2.0.3 the argument type is str  `parser.add_argument('--file', type=str)`

Comment: I'm not sure if `type=file` used to work, but it don't work now. If you're attempting to get the filename, use `type=str`.